# iOS Swipe to Delete Array in plist from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and in each row is the name of an `array` in a `plist`. This means that when I try and use the normal swipe to delete method of:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]
```

The app crashes. How can I tell the swipe to delete to find the array in the plist and delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to delete the row being displayed in the table view. You also have to remove the item from your data array. Presumably you have a `NSMutableArray` that reads in the plist at the beginning. (If it is just an `NSArray`, change it to mutable!)

Just after deleting the row, delete the data from the array

```
[myDataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

If you have sections, you first would have to figure out the position of your object in the array, but the principle is the same.

You can now optionally write the changes to disk by overwriting your existing plist with the contents of your data array.

Comment: This is how my app finds the plist.. It doesn't work just changing it.. `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 // get documents path
 NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 // get the path to our Data/plist file
 NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)plistPath];`

Comment: Sure it does. Just do the same with a `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: I tried `[dictionary removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`, still causes a crash

Comment: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Comment: Of course. There is no `removeObjectAtIndex` in dictionaries. Read up on your API! First get the array holding your rows from the dictionary, and then remove from this array.

Comment: I don't have access from that method to the label of the row (which is the key).. how can I find the array?

Comment: (I'm trying to use `[dictionary removeObjectForKey:]` but obviously I have to have a way to programatically get the key...

Comment: Do you homework and you will figure it out. If you need the key, just look at your plist file. But then again, I am sure you have already done that...

Comment: I know what the key is - the array has the same name as the row in the table that i'm trying to get it to delete, I'm just trying to figure out how to grab that from the tableview

Comment: Then you should accept this answer and post a new question. ;-)